# Current Month and year in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am currently new in C# & SQL.

How do I get the current month and year in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Those are two very different questions.

Comment: You shouldn't need to go right back to the database to get the current month and year, just to display it on a webpage. `DateTime.Today` in C# will suffice

Answer (score 24, accepted):

SQL Server

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime
     , YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CurrentYear
     , MONTH(GETDATE()) AS CurrentMonth
```

C#

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var currentYear = now.Year;
var currentMonth = now.Month;
```

Comment: Thanks So much is the any way that i can convert the current datetime to Seconds/minutes??